# Работа с bitrix API

Tags: php, битрикс

1) Каким образом, или с помощью каких классов и событий (API) можно поменять иконку раздела, или поменять цвет шрифта у того раздела, у которого установлено некое свойство.

Например, я устанавливаю для разделов пользовательское свойство, и в зависимости от значения этого свойства, нужно в административной панели изменять иконку данного раздела на любую другою, или сделать шрифт красным.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2) Каким образом можно можно в форме редактирования элемента, у некого свойства с кодом "ATT_BRAND", задать событие `onClick` c вызовом js скрипта?

Подробнее:

В настройке инфоблока, в поле "Файл с формой редактирования элемента:" я подключил свой php файл, вставил туда код, как написано в документации, в этом коде нашел участок кода где идет вывод свойств через функцию `_ShowPropertyField`, чуть выше кода вывода свойств я написал это:

```
<? 

if($prop_fields["CODE"] == "ATT_BRAND") { 

... 

} 

?>
```

Каким образом теперь этому свойству(input'у) добавить свое событие ?

Comment: мне кажется Вам стоит задать ***два*** вопроса

Comment: ну почему же не в тему: Вы задали вопрос в котором спрашиваете о 2 не связанных вещах :) Так что это скорее всего два, и двум вопросам можно было бы дать более понятные темы, что то типа: *Как изменить стиль пункта меню в админке по условию*, *Как добавить событие для пользовательского элемента*. и тогда Ваш вопрос был бы более ценен, потому что кому то он мог бы помочь, а в текущей постановке будет сложно найти

Comment: Хорошо, что бы это изменило? На что бы повлияло.

Comment: два конкретных вопроса, лучше чем один расплывчатый

Comment: А в чем у меня вопрос не конкретный?

Comment: @DDDDDDDDD, тем что это **два** не связанных между собой вопроса. Соответственно они имеют **два** не связанных между собой решения, следовательно их стоит задать по отдельности

Comment: @DDDDDDDDD, *Хорошо, что бы это изменило?* - правила сообщества, в котором вы задаете вопросы, были бы соблюдены, например.

Answer (score 2):

По первому вопросу, не надо лезть в админку, а то придут обновы и все может обнулиться.
По второму вопросу:

Если `$prop_code` это ключ массива в котором сидит символьный код то:

```
<input type="button" value="Отправить" <?if($prop_code == "ATT_BRAND"):?>onClick=""<?endif?> />
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

1) Я не хочу затрагивать ядро. А нет каких-то методов которое изменяет поведение ядра? Я так понимаю это нереализуемо без изменения движка?

2) ATT_BRAND это у меня текстовое поле, и его в коде нет что бы ему таким образом добавить событие. Это поле (свойство) добавляется через функцию _ShowPropertyField

Comment: 1) Вообще все что есть в админке лежит в папке /bitrix/admin/, можете изменить все что угодно. Но опять же зачем вам это непонятно. 2) ничего не понял))

Comment: 1) Т.е. при обновлении /bitrix/admin/ не перезаписывается ?  так заказчик захотел, если у раздело установленное пользовательское свойство с определенным значением, то подсвечивать этот раздел.

2) https://i.gyazo.com/f37a7782d27dddbf664fadf4b1cbfaf8.png

в этом месте идет перебор всех свойств и их вывод.

В `$prop_fields` свойства(id,name,value, ..) текущего свойства (input'a) который будет выводиться в панели.

И я проверяю `if($prop_fields["CODE"] == "ATT_BRAND")` то нужно каким то образом у этого свойства ($prop_fields) установить свое событие.